# Java Enum types not being recognized by my methods

Tags: java, enums

Currently developing a code smell detector for a uni assignment. I have made an abstract CodeSmell class, with two concrete subclasses - ClassLevelSmell and MethodLevelSmell. The CodeSmell class has a protected field of type SmellType. A sample constructor is as follows:

```
public ClassLevelSmell(ClassDefinition classDef, SmellType type){
    smellyClass = classDef;
    this.smell = type;
}
```

SmellType is an enum I defined, which looks like this:

```
public enum SmellType {
LONG_CLASS, LONG_METHOD, PRIMITIVE_OBSESSION, LONG_PARAM_LIST}
```

I then have a SmellDetector object, with numerous methods that compare the statistics of analyzed classes and methods (such as their number of lines, number of primitive declarations etc) and creates a new CodeSmell object if a smell is found. So my code for this looks like this:

```
    private void detectLongClass(ClassDefinition classDef) {
    if(classDef.getNumLines() > 250){
        smells.add(new ClassLevelSmell(classDef, LONG_CLASS));
    }
}
```

Each SmellDetector object has a field *smells*, an ArrayList of CodeSmells. However, I'm getting a compiler warning in eclipse when I try to pass the SmellType LONG_CLASS into the constructor for the ClassLevelMethod, telling me "LONG_CLASS cannot be resolved to a variable". Am I making some mistake with the use of Enumerated types? What do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To reference enum values you either need to use the qualified form with the class name or use static imports. So either make it:

```
smells.add(new ClassLevelSmell(classDef, SmellType.LONG_CLASS));
```

or do this:

```
// at the top of your file:
import static packagename.SmellType.*;

smells.add(new ClassLevelSmell(classDef, LONG_CLASS));
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
smells.add(new ClassLevelSmell(classDef, SmellType.LONG_CLASS));
```